# JSF link in SelectItem label

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, selectonemenu

Is it possible to set a `<a href />`around my `<f:selectItem itemLabel="label" />` where my link text is the `itemLabel`?

I'm using the plain sun components.

Comment: is the desired result possible in HTML? 
What is the parent of f:selectItem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The desired result is **not** possible in HTML. You'll need to add a shot of JavaScript for this.

```xhtml
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.links}" />
<h:selectOneMenu>
```

Where `bean.getLinks()` returns a `List<SelectItem>` with a fullworthy URL as item **value**. If you want to show the link as *both* value and label, just use the `SelectItem` constructor taking a single argument.

```java
links = new List<SelectItem>();
links.add(new SelectItem("http://google.com"));
links.add(new SelectItem("http://stackoverflow.com"));
// ...
```

If you want to hardcode them in the view, then you can of course grab `f:selectItem`:

```xhtml
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="http://google.com" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="http://stackoverflow.com" />
<h:selectOneMenu>
```